# php-bcmath error - extension not loaded in php7

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, php-extension, amazon-ami

I don't know, why do I always come up with weird errors here :D.

**Recently I have been facing an error, most like related to PHP-bcmath extension for php7.**

The extension is installed in the environment, yet it's not loaded onto the system.

This is confirmed by as when I try to install the extension, this message is shown:

Package php-bcmath-7.0.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

It's related to WordPress and I'm using amazon AMI Linux to host a WordPress environment.

This extension is required to use a plugin called Wp-Statistics, and I need PHP-bcmath to show the geo-location function.

I tried to install the same extension in another environment which was also a Wordpress site running on Debian, the extension was successfully loaded and the plugin was working well.

Now for this AMI Linux, Is there any way around to load the extension as it says that it's already installed ?

Answer (score 1):

open `/etc/apt/sources.list` in editor

add:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/debian/ sid main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/debian/ sid main
```

run `apt-get update`

and run:

```
apt-get install  php7.0-bcmath
```